# Why is autotest not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, autotest

I changed my `.autotest` file to use it with a Ruby-based project.

After that, when I wanted to use it for Rails, it is using the `.autotest` configuration settings I used for the Ruby project.

I uninstalled autotest and reinstalled it with no luck.
I also removed the `.autotest` file in the root directory but it is not working.

Comment: In English, sentences begin with a capital, and the word "I" is capitalized.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm trying to get autotest up and running as well. I just installed the gem. Running `autotest` or `autotest --rails` inside my rails app starts autotest, but it doesn't runs a single test. It reports that there aren't any.

---

UPDATE:

Just discovered I needed to install `autotest-rails` as well.

You should also install `autotest-fsevent` to make sure that autotest isn't polling all the time.

I've posted the results of my day of autotest at http://ryanbooker.com/archive/autotest-your-rails-apps.

The Short story:

```
sudo gem install ZenTest autotest-rails autotest-fsevent autotest-growl redgreen
```

Edit your ~/.autotest

```
# Include plugins
require 'autotest/fsevent'
require 'autotest/growl'
require 'redgreen/autotest' # yes this is correct

# Skip some paths
Autotest.add_hook :initialize do |autotest|
  %w{.git .DS_Store ._* vendor}.each { |exception| autotest.add_exception(exception) }
  false
end
```

You can launch autotest with:

```
cd myrailsapp
autotest
```

Comment: FWIW: I was getting some issues when including 'autotest-rails' in my develompent.rb file. I switched to just config.gem 'autotest' and it all seemed to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

how are you launching autotest?  If you use `autotest --rails` it should definitely work.

Comment: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby -I.:lib:test -rubygems -e "%w[test/unit test/shoulda_macros/searchable.rb test/functional/test_controller_test.rb test/test_helper.rb].each { |f| require f }" | unit_diff -u


nope, above is the initial trace of autotest --rails

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Rails 3.1 or higher, I highly recommend using guard for TDD with rspec. It works like magic.  https://github.com/guard/guard